# How to serve big files using WKURLSchemeHandler?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview, wkurlschemehandler

I am using `WKURLSchemeHandler` to serve local files that cannot be read directly by the `WkWebView`. While it works fine for small files like videos, it totally freezes the application when it has to provide big files like videos.

Right now, I am reading the full file in a single step which is inappropriate for important files.

```
data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
```

How should I do in order to avoid this? Is there a way to "stream" the content of the file?

Answer (score 1):

`didReceive(Data)` is special and can be called multiple times with partial data, so chunked reading/streaming is possible. It's not obvious from the docs, but they said so at their presentation uf the scheme handler feature (see 32:30): https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/220/

Furthermore, `WKURLSchemeTask`'s functions can be called on a background thread, no need to do it on the main thread (and potentially blocking the UI).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Are you aware of any sample code showing how to stream data in the response?

Comment: @RichardLovejoy There is another SO question that has a sample implementation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216563/how-to-enable-wkurlschemehandler-to-do-work-off-main-thread