# WKURLSchemeHandler NSInternalInconsistencyException with Task cancellation

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, swift-concurrency, wkurlschemehandler

I have a problem with `WKURLSchemeHandler` and Task cancellation and provided an example implementation below.

The problem is, that *sometimes* right after `webView(_:stop:)` is called (and "Stopping task ..." is printed) either `try Task.checkCancellation()` does not throw, or has already been called (I am not sure), so one of the `urlSchemeTask.didReceive` or `didFinish` can crash the app with an Exeption like this:

```
Stopping task <WKURLSchemeTaskImpl: 0x7fd445c209c0>
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This task has already been stopped'
```

Example implementation with comments:

```swift
import WebKit

class AsyncURLSchemeHandler: NSObject, WKURLSchemeHandler {
    private var pendingTasks = [ObjectIdentifier: TaskItem]()
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        guard let task = pendingTasks.removeValue(forKey: urlSchemeTask.id) else { return }
        print("Stopping task \(urlSchemeTask)")
        task.stop()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        let task = Task { [weak self] in
            var request = urlSchemeTask.request
        
            // Do some mutation on the request
            
            do {
                try Task.checkCancellation()
                
                 // Conditionally get a URLSession 
                let session: URLSession 
                
                // Fire off the request
                let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request)
                
                await Task.yield()
                try Task.checkCancellation()

                // Report back to the scheme task
                // Either of these !! may crash in this implementation
                urlSchemeTask.didReceive(response) // !!
                urlSchemeTask.didReceive(data) // !!
                urlSchemeTask.didFinish() // !!
                
            } catch is CancellationError {
                // Do not call didFailWithError, didFinish, or didReceive in this case
                print("Task for WKURLSchemeTask \(urlSchemeTask) has been cancelled")
            } catch {
                if !Task.isCancelled {
                    // !! This can crash, too
                    urlSchemeTask.didFailWithError(error)
                }
            }
            
            self?.pendingTasks.removeValue(forKey: urlSchemeTask.id)
        }
        
        pendingTasks[urlSchemeTask.id] = .init(urlSchemeTask: urlSchemeTask, task: task)
    }
}

private extension WKURLSchemeTask {
    var id: ObjectIdentifier {
        ObjectIdentifier(self)
    }
}

private struct TaskItem {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case manualCancellation
    }
    
    let urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask
    let task: Task<Void, Never>
    
    /// Should be called when urlSchemeTask has been stopped by the system
    /// Calling anything on the urlSchemeTask afterwards would result in an exception
    func stop() {
        task.cancel()
    }
    
    /// Should be called when the urlSchemeTask should be stopped manually
    func cancel() {
        task.cancel()
        urlSchemeTask.didFailWithError(Error.manualCancellation)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to avoid these crashes?

This is a crosspost of: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this i do the following:

- I wrap the pending Task state in an actor
- I use a `Set<ObjectIdentifier>` in that actor and checked `contains` instead of using task cancellation.
- I use an approach like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35003095/5771177) to catch the objc exception and ignore it

Most importantly:

- The main issue is out of scope of this question, I restructure the things around to fix the WebView lifecycle.

Comment: would you mind sharing an example of the solution you found?

Comment: UPDATE: i found a solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69256003/1641160

Comment: @BlakeRegalia it's working well for you?

Comment: @aehlke it took some tweaks but your mention of using the hash makes a lot more sense and seems promising